# How can I prevent position:fixed elements from overlapping their parent

Tags: css, css-position

I ran into this issue trying to implement https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders in an application. In my case, everything worked fine, but the header was visible outside of the container. Once it had position:fixed, it suddenly ignored z-index and overflow properties. I set up the following fiddle to demonstrate the issue:

```
.scroller{
    overflow:scroll;
    width:200px;
    margin:2em auto;
}

.container{
    width:400px;
    background:green;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.foobar {
    width:350px;
    height:10px;
    position:fixed;
    background:yellow;
    opacity:0.5;
    margin-left:-25px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z2x5Q/1/

How can I keep the .foobar div's width and fixed position, without it overlapping the div.container's boundaries?

Comment: What's your desired result? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Add this to your container: `.container { position: relative; z-index: 1; }`

Comment: @Malcoda A table with the fixed headers plugin, similar to the effect shown on the fiddle: the headers overlap their parent container horizontally. For this scenario, I need them to obey the overflow-x:scroll of their parent. Luckily, the issue is easily reproduced without any javascript in pure CSS :) So ideally in this fiddle, I'd want the yellow bar to be clipped inside the green box's boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to use `position: fixed`?

The problems you state are a standard behavior of a fixed position. The item is moved out of the flow of the DOM and you are required to explicitly state where and how you want it. I'm not sure `position: fixed` is giving you anything here that you would want. In fact, as soon as you take that property off your `.foobar` element, it looks like you get the behavior you want.

I'd suggest reading up a bit more on position fixed.

Good article here from [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/)

Comment: Explained in my previous response. I'm sure the question would make more sense in it's real application, but I'm unable to share the original. Luckily as stated, the issue is clear in the fiddle. The original question still stands.